# Centering element inside scrollable area

Tags: javascript

I have long ul element filled with li. Horizontal scroll is enabled so only few `<li>` are visible at the same time.

```
<ul id="longScrollableDiv">
   <li><a href="centerMe()">CenterMe</a></li> 
   <li><a href="centerMe()">CenterMe</a></li>
   <li><a href="centerMe()">CenterMe</a></li>
   <li><a href="centerMe()">CenterMe</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want centerMe() to center selected  in the currently visible area of the div, so the selected a would be if possible in the center of the view.
How can I obtain this? `scrollIntoView()` doesn't center elements. I'd like no jQuery approach if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yor have to add onclick handler for all list items which do something like this

```
target.parentNode.scrollTop = (target.offsetTop - target.parentNode.offsetTop) -
Math.round(target.parentNode.offsetHeight/2) + Math.round(target.offsetHeight/2) ;
```

The working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TfVTz/6/)

Comment: And special for ie7 and ie6 the code must be modified to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TfVTz/7/) (it works properly only in i6 and ie7)